# how to display list in descending order using query() in stead of rawQuery()? android

Tags: android

I try to user the following code to display my list in a descending order order by KEY_TIME, but it doesn't work, I tried rawQuery as well, but the program dead after I run it, please help me find the mistake, thanks!

```
   return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
    KEY_BODY, KEY_TIME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_ALARM}, null, null,null,KEY_TIME+"DESC",null);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code,

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
        KEY_BODY, KEY_TIME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_ALARM}, null, null,null,null,KEY_TIME+" DESC");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try placing a space in between KEY_TIME and "DESC", it seems like they would be running together and SQLite wouldn't be able to find the key specified.  You'll also want it to be in the last position of the query():

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
    KEY_BODY, KEY_TIME, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_ALARM}, null, null,null,null, KEY_TIME +" DESC");
```

Give that a shot